Which is preferred over differential pairs: trombones or sawtooths?
I have been told that trombones are much better to use than sawtooths, even if sawtooths may be prefered in some certians scenarios.
Here I have added trombones to the differential pairs. If I had been using sawtooths, then the impedance would take damage becuase this extra "path" spares the impedance.
Let's summarize the pros and cones by using tromebones and sawtooths:
Sawtooths

Pros: The sawtooth can delay the signal at each corner, which makes the signal follow the same symmetrical speed
Cons: The sawtooth violates the signal integrity (impedance)

Trombone

Pros: The trombone spares the signal integrity (impedance)
Cons: The trombone make the signal not symmetrical in speed

Whether by using sawtooth or tromebone, the signals will arrive at the same time.
Question:
Which one is preferred when it comes to differential pairs?
This picture shows Giggabit Ethernet traces to an RJ45 connector. The impedance must be 100 ohms.

This picture shows HDMI traces to a HDMI connector. The impedance must be 100 ohms.

This picture shows USB OTG connection. The impedance must be 90 ohms.

This picture shows DDR connections. The impedance must be 100 ohms.


The reason of the use of differential pairs is to reduce emissions and susceptibility.

@Andyaka Sure, the diff pair is more robust to noise. But the signals need to arrive at the same time. That can be achieved by using sawtoots or tromebones. But which one is prefered?

Can you give an example of sawtooths? The problem is that when you are told something is better, it may be specific to some certain case, or a huge generalization. Sometimes, the correct answer is neither, because it may be better to not mess the impedance match with serpentine tracks, but to allow for mismatch in intra-pair length if it's within tolerance. Looks like your trombones bulge a lot so the impedance discontinuity may be more than you want. Also mention what signals those are and what are your specs for it - I have to assume Ethernet, but is that 100M or Gigabit or what?

@Justme Yes, my trombones bulge a lot, but a sawtooth will bulge even more. The impedance must be 100 ohms. My thought is that a sawtooth violates the impedance requirments, when a tromebone violates less. It's Gigabit Ethernet.

@Justme I see lot of people using some kind of extra path for differential pairs.

I'm not a PCB designer, but does the Altium article Switchback Routing vs. Serpentine Traces Routing for Maximum Density help for some other routing techniques to consider?

I rank sawtooths last.  A 45 degree, or even 30 degree trace angle has more of a micro-impedance-discontinuity than a true curve.  The sawtooth is faster to route, especially manually, but at 1 G, or especially 10 G, those micros add up.

@AnalogKid So you recommend me to use my current routing? (The RJ45 bulge might need a nice re-routing). I mean, if the differential pairs should always have the same length?

@euraad Yes, differential pairs should always have the same length. However, if you are within the allowed tolerance even without doing it, then it's better not to do it and cause impedance discontinuities by adding squiggly bits of wiring.

Differential signals have their main advantage in being indifferent to GND offsets between transmitter and receiver.

Which of your examples are you calling "trombones" and which are you calling "sawtooths"? I have a good idea what you mean by a "trombone", but I haven't heard of a "sawtooth" design before, so it's hard for me to understand your question. Also when you say "spares the impedance", do you mean it preserves the impedance?

@Justme, the "allowed tolerances" might ensure achieving low bit error rate on the connection, but they probably don't guarantee meeting radiated emissions requirements.

@ThePhoton Yes that could be a problem. However, if you do length matching with squiggles, meeting radiated emissions is useless, if you can't pass Ethernet/HDMI/USB compliance tests due to problems caused by doing the length matching. For the EMI, one can use provisions for SMD CM chokes on diff pairs if EMI is a problem, or fit 0R jumpes if it wasn't a problem.

In your first three examples, the differential pairs do not appear to be particularly tightly coupled. The trace separation is at least 4x the trace width. This means that the impedance discontinuity due to the trombone is likely to be quite small. If you want to know how much, re-calculate your differential pair impedance with the same trace widths and height above ground, but with the trace separation increased to some very large number (10 mm, or whatever). Very likely for the geometries shown, it will still be 100 ohms +/- a few ohms.
The 4th example might show traces closely enough coupled for the trombone to adversely affect the characteristic impedance. In that case, one possible solution is to widen the track slightly in the trombone sections to increase the capacitance between track and ground, compensating for the reduced capacitance track-to-track. This is a bit fussy to do in CAD, but it is possible.
Working at 1 Gbps, the examples you showed would be adequate as-is for many applications. At 25 Gbps, you'd want to be using curves rather than 45-degree bends to form your trombones, and you'd want to use EM simulation (HFSS, for example) to verify your design (for reflection, transmission, and mode conversion) before manufacturing in any case, and you could use the results of that simulation to improve the design as needed.

So you're telling me that my routing for these specific trombones won't disturbe the computed impedance so much? My tolerance for the impedance is about 10% i guess.

@euraad, probably not. If you want to know for sure, do the calculation.

Thank you. Can I just compute the impedance with a different space? For example, the space is 0.24mm for the DDR diff-pair and with that trombone, its 0.581 mm.

@euraad, just compare the geometry you have, to the same geometry but with the track-to-track spacing increased to a large number. You could use 10x the track width or the actual largest spacing in your trombone structure or whatever. Or calculate the single-ended impedance for a single isolated track and double it. You'll get very close to the same result with any of these methods.

Sorry, the normal spacing is 0.14mm and the trombone spacing is 0.5mm. For 0.14mm, it requries 0.09mm in width. For 0.5mm in spacning, it requires 0.11mm in width. So 0.03mm in difference.

Calculate the resulting Z0 if you keep the width the same, not the required width to keep 100 ohms.

Is the resulting Z0 some kind of average? I know that Z0 is the track impedance. When when you said "resulting"...of...many different result?

Step 1: Find the characteristic impedance of your differential traces if you increase the trace separation by "a lot". Step 2: Compare it to the characteristic impedance you had with the original geometry. Step 3: Ask yourself, "is this difference big enough to worry about?". There is no averaging to be done here.

Which one is better depends on the application and. They are both sort of bad anyway. If you want to maximize the total signal integrity for best performance (for whatever metric that is), you don't only minimize length difference or impedance mismatch - sometimes a perfectly valid option to maximize signal integrity and minimize impedance mismatch and reflections is to allow intra-pair length mismatch.
Both techniques cause an impedance mismatch, the other causes a short mismatch due to a single bulge, and the other causes a long mismatch due to longer length of sawtooths needed. In the end the sawtooths are just many small bulges in series.
So if you have calculated an impedance for a given trace with and separation, any deviations to that, whether or not sawtooths or trombone bulges, means that you are deviating from the impedance. This can of course be compensated by calculating or simulating the effect and using better parameters during the sawtooth or bulges.
The giveaway is, why not any other technique like smooth tracks to begin with with specified circular turns with specified turn diameters for the arcs to compensate for length differences? It would use more PCB area and might not be able to compensate the intra-pair difference right where it happens so it would take longer for the signal to travel with mismatch until the delay is equal.
